# WIFI USB adapter not detected

Tags: raspbian, networking, usb, wifi

I'm using a WIFI USB adapter : TP-Link TL-WN725N Nano Adaptateur USB wireless N 150 Mbps. I plug it to my raspberry and configured it in `/etc/network/interfaces` . I added this :

```
allow-hotplug wlan0 
iface wlan0 inet dhcp 
wpa-ssid "MY NETWORK SSID"
```

I dont need password to connect.

then `sudo reboot`

when I launch `ifconfig` I got this (no wlan detected).

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:d5:44:b8  
          inet addr:192.168.0.2  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:53 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:90 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:7022 (6.8 KiB)  TX bytes:9278 (9.0 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:14 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:14 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1330 (1.2 KiB)  TX bytes:1330 (1.2 KiB)
```

Comment: Just after you plug the dongle in you should see some messages about the dongle in dmesg (command line type dmesg).  It would be useful if you could post the lines related to the dongle.  Also the lsusb -v lines related to the dongle may be of interest.

Comment: after search, this is no driver for TP-Link TL-WN725N V2  under linux. there is driver in gitub http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=29752 .compile and insert it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it works for me by installing the right driver

```
wget https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/80256631/8188eu-20140307.tar.gz
tar -zxvf 8188eu-20140307.tar.gz
sudo cp rtl8188eufw.bin /lib/firmware/rtlwifi //not needed anymore if your operating system is above 3.10.33+
sudo install -p -m 644 8188eu.ko /lib/modules/3.10.33+/kernel/drivers/net/wireless
sudo insmod /lib/modules/3.10.33+/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/8188eu.ko
sudo depmod -a
sudo reboot
```

my kernel version is 3.10.33+

Comment: When I do this I get `Invalid Module Format`

Answer (score 5):

Check out this [tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20150408150941/http://omer.me/2012/04/setting-up-wireless-networks-under-debian-on-raspberry-pi/)

I think you need to install the drivers. Since url answers my disappear, here is what it basically says:

Now, plug your USB wifi adapter to one of the ports and issue: lsusb. You should see something along the lines of:

```
$ lsusb

...
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0ace:1215 ZyDAS ZD1211B 802.11g
...
```

Okay, it looks like the chipset we have here is ‘zd1211′ (Have a look at http://wiki.debian.org/WiFi for a list of supported chipsets)

Let’s see if there are any firmware packages we can install to get this up and running:

```
$ apt-cache search zd1211
```

zd1211-firmware - Firmware images for the zd1211rw wireless driver

Sweet, let’s install that:

```
$ sudo apt-get install zd1211-firmware
```

We should be good to go now. Unplug the adapter, plug it back in again and have a look at the output of lsmod:

```
$ lsmod

Module   Size   Used by
arc      4764   2
zd1211rw 40444  0
mac80211 171628 1 zd1211rw
cfg80211 123084 2 zd1211rw,mac80211
fuse     49036  1
```

You should see mention of zd1211.

dmesg should also give you an indication whether things are loaded or not:

```
    $ dmesg

...
usb 1-1.2: new high speed USB device number 4 using dwc_otg
usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0ace, idProduct=1215
usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=16, Product=32, SerialNumber=0
usb 1-1.2: Product: USB2.0 WLAN
usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: ZyDAS
cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
usb 1-1.2: reset high speed USB device number 4 using dwc_otg
ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'minstrel_ht'
zd1211rw 1-1.2:1.0: phy0
usbcore: registered new interface driver zd1211rw
zd1211rw 1-1.2:1.0: firmware version 4725
zd1211rw 1-1.2:1.0: zd1211b chip 0ace:1215 v4810 high 00-1a-ee UW2453_RF pa0 -7---
...
```

Awesome, looks like the adapter is up and running! To see which networks are available, do:

```
$ iwlist wlan0 scan
```

…which should give you a list of wireless networks around you.

Good luck

Comment: I am not entirely sure what drivers I need

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to install the proper driver according to your kernel/build OS distribution.

I found my driver for Realtek 8192eu (Mercusys MW300UM USB WiFi Adaptor) on http://downloads.fars-robotics.net/wifi-drivers/8192eu-drivers/

1. Run `uname -a` to get your "kernel" and "build", e.g

   ```
    $ uname -a
    Linux raspberrypi 5.10.3-v7+ #1386 SMP Sun Dec 27 14:01:57 GMT 2020 armv7l
   ```

   The kernel is "5.10.3-v7+" and build is "1386"
2. Download into RPi from above URL link the firmware which is the most suitable to your kernel/build (e.g `8192eu-5.10.3-v7-1386.tar.gz`, pay attention because multiple versions could be found)
3. Run `tar -zxvf 8192eu-5.10.3-v7-1386.tar.gz` into the location where the download was done at step 2
4. Run `./install.sh`
5. Run `sudo insmod /lib/modules/5.10.3-v7+/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/8192eu.ko`
6. Run `sudo depmod -a`
7. Run `sudo reboot`

Comment: This one worked for me for usb dongle TP-Link RTL8812AU Archer T4U 802.11ac, didn't find the exact #1496 on the site, chose the closest one (the highest was 13xx)

Answer (score 0):

You should also check that the wifi devices are not blocked by `rfkill` - you can do so like this:

```
rfkill list wifi
```

If any are listed as blocked you can unblock all wifi devices using this command:

```
sudo rfkill unblock wifi
```

Or just enable/unblock a specific one by adding its index (from the rfkill list) e.g:

```
sudo rfkill unblock wifi 0
```