# Using onboard wifi chip (wlan0) and wifi adapter (wlan1) to implement a virtual router

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, wifi

I'm attempting to share the wifi connection of the onboard wifi chip (wlan0) with my other devices using a wifi adapter (wlan1). The problem I am currently facing is that the wifi adapter is not showing up as wlan1. It appears in `lsusb` as `Bus 001 Device 008: ID 13b1:0042 Linksys` but not when I run `ifconfig`. Only wlan0 appears.

I've looked in the following locations without any luck:

- [Enable wlan0 and wlan1](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/46192/enable-wlan0-and-wlan1)
- [WIFI USB adapter not detected](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15380/wifi-usb-adapter-not-detected)
- https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=138730
- https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=49283

The current Raspbian version (one that comes with NOOBS) I am using also doesn't contain 
`/lib/udev/rules.d/75-persistent-net-generator.rules` which I see commonly discussed when the topic of two wifi adaptors is brought up on forums.

Any help or guidance with solving this would be appreciated.

Comment: "My goal is to implement this tutorial" do you want us to read the tutorial and guess **WHAT you did** - you are likely to get more response if you tell us **WHAT you ACTUALLY did** also tell us WHAT Raspbian.

Comment: Remove that line and my question doesn't change. The wifi adapter is not showing up under wlan1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ifconfig` only shows interfaces that are in  an "up" state.  `ifconfig -a` will show all of them, but as per the man page:

> This program is obsolete!  For replacement check ip addr and ip link.

Which doesn't mean it is going anywhere, but you might as well use `ip link`, which will also show everything.

If it still doesn't show up, it's probably [because of this](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/Linksys_WUSB6100M) -- note no available linux driver.  That's unusual, but to spare yourself grief you should check around before buying.  My recommendation about wifi drivers is to get them from a brick and mortar place close by that will take a return or exchange no questions asked within a short period of time.

However, grepping through the kernel source, I found the ID registered and "Linksys WUSB6100M" in corresponding comments.  Unfortunately, it is for the `ath10k_usb` driver which

> This module adds experimental support for USB bus. Currently
>             work in progress and will not fully work.

These are not necessarily up to date though and "fully work" is ambiguous.  Try `lsmod | grep ath` and see if anything shows up.  If not, try `sudo modprobe ath10k_usb`.